# vim - Cursor randomly jumps on Linux

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

This only occurs when I am using vim on Linux (it's Kali Linux to be precise, though I haven't tested it on other distributions). I am using a standard German keyboard layout.

Sometimes when I type in vim (it often happens when I exit insert mode or when I use `:w`, maybe only on one of these since I often do one after the other), the cursor randomly jumps elsewhere, usually about 100 lines upwards (I don't have an exact number). At the same time, the next number in the line my cursor was in is decremented.

I suspect that this happens because I hit some sequence of keys to quickly, since this, on my Linux distribution, can cause some special characters to be inserted due to one of the keys modifying the other. For example, if I type "yt" quickly with this keyboard, it becomes "yŧ" (with a second bar on the t)

This by itself is somewhat annoying to me so if someone knows a way to turn that off on Linux while still retaining the basic keyboard layout, this would solve my problem, but telling me the exact command I accidentally executed so I can avoid/remove it will also help.

As far as I can remember, this problem only occurred when I was editing `.tex`files, but that is also what I have been using vim the most for recently, so I wouldn't assume that it only happens there.
Still, I can post my list of plugins and my `.vimrc` if necessary. Just in case it has something to do with only LaTeX files, the only vim plugin I have for that is `vimtex`.

Comment: I considered doing that but I noticed that almost all Vim-related questions are asked on this site. Since this question mostly concerns Vim and the Linux part probably only affects the characters fed into Vim, I still think that this is the appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is mapped to control + x by default. It decrements the next number on the given line.

Comment: I looked that up but that still doesn't explain how the cursor randomly jumps